# Obtener valor url Laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Laravel, y es nuevo para mi, por lo que tengo algunos problemas.

Estoy haciendo que en una lista de productos, que tienen un botón para editarlos, obtener el id del mismo, para luego lanzar la ventana para editar la información del mismo, y actualmente lo que hago es, desde el home, con el route, enviar el código de referencia:

```
{{route('ProductEdit', [$product->reference])}}
```

Luego, tengo en el arvhivo web.php, lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('/ProductEdit', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'edit'])->name('ProductEdit');
```

Y en el enlace de cuando pulso sobre el botón para editar, si aparece el código de referencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, después de ?.

En el controller, tengo puesto para ver que información le llega, lo siguiente:

```
  public function edit(Request $request)
{
   $url = url()->current();

    echo("Hola Edit ->$url " );

    return view('NewProduct');

}
```

Pero la url que aparece es solo hasta public/ProductEdit, sin el código que hay detrás del ?, por lo que me gustaría saber como obtenerlo para después poder buscar el producto en mi BD y obtener sus datos.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesar de que envías correctamente el id, no lo recibes en el método del controlador correctamente. Si pasas por [acá](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters), te darás cuenta que en tu método debes añadir la variable con que recibirás ese parámetro de ruta. Por lo tanto, tu controlador debería quedar así:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $product)
{
   return dd($product);

}
```

Así notarás que efectivamente está llegando tu parámetro. Por añadidura, deberías comprobar si tu parámetro debería ser obligatorio o no. Si lees en enlace, te darás cuenta la manera de usarlo, pero solo deberías hacer:

```
Route::get('/ProductEdit/{product}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'edit'])
->name('ProductEdit');
```

O si es opcional:

```
Route::get('/ProductEdit/{product?}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'edit'])
->name('ProductEdit');
```